# Replace name is not working in Powershell for replacing special characters ( | ? ! & )

Tags: powershell, replace, rename

I have been going off of stack overflow and chat gpt information to put this script together.
It's not working in replacing/removing a special charaters from every file name in a directory. the commands execute typically with no errors but it's weird that it's just not working.

I have file names that look like
"abc def xyz? part 1.mp4"
"abc def xyz? part 2.mp4"
....

there are various file names that may have a ? , | , ! , or & and i want to remove all that characters.
Below is the only code that worked....

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Name -replace '｜', '') }
```

I tried to replace the | with ? and i get "InvalidOperation: The regular expression pattern ? is not valid."

I have tried to escape thge ? with both \ and ` and those dont return errors but do not change the file names.

I think this should be working but i'm lost on why it's not.
I'm using 7.2.15 powershell.

Comment: `-Replace` is a RegEx based operator, meaning, certain tokens (*characters*) like `|` have a special meaning in RegEx. Either escape them  using a backslash, or use the .Net `.Replace()` method to do so for a literal take: `Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.Replace([char[]]'?!|','') } `.

Comment: hello, i did get new results when i tried this, but this took away the file extension of .mp4

Comment: PowerShell's `-replace` operator is [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based. Regex _metacharacters_ (those with special meaning), namely `\ ( ) | . * + ? ^ $ [ {`, need to be ``\``-_escaped_ in order to be used _verbatim_; escape whole strings with `[regex]::Escape()`. Alternatively, use the `[string]` type's `.Replace()` method for verbatim replacements, but note that it is case-_sensitive_, _invariably_ in Windows PowerShell, and _by default_ in PowerShell (Core) 6+. See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: Pardon my mistake, I was also thinking of the `.Split()` method when I casted `[char[]]` to it. It should be `Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace '\?|\||!}`

Comment: Alternatively, use a regex character set (`[...]`): `Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '[?|!&]' }`

Comment: thanks for everyone's help... it's almost there.... this command is doing everything correctly except it cannot get rid of the "?" .....  Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Name -replace '\?|\||!', '') }

Comment: @The_BMan: Given that `'a|?&!b' -replace '[?|!&]'` succeeds in removing all characters of interest, including `?`, the problem must lie elsewhere. In case you're running this on Windows: Note that you normally aren't permitted to create file names that contain `|` and `?`, among other characters.

Comment: i think i know what the problem is.... the file names have a different looking ? within their names.... not sure how this happened... they are both ascii code 63 according to excel....  here is the exact  question mark i struggling to replace... ？  vs ?  i dont know what the difference is between these just yet but the pwsh command is working now...

Comment: It is `？`, the FULLWIDTH QUESTION MARK, [`U+FF1F`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff1f)), distinct from the ASCII-range `?`, the QUESTION MARK, [`U+003F`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3f)). You can use the former in the regex too.

Comment: wow, this new ? is new to me... so i would need to include both in my serach text... yeesh! thank you all for your help